# Provide markdown styling to QML Markdown Text?

Tags: qt, qml

Since Qt 5.14 QML has been able to natively have Markdown rendering using `Text.Markdown` however, this is with a default style. I was wondering if there is a current option to provide a custom style for the rendered Markdown by QML.

Another option is to covert to `html` and then add a css style sheet during the rendering but I'm looking to see if there is anything available with the native QML.

Comment: looking at https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextmarkdownimporter.cpp.html (and QTextMarkdownWriter) it seems not possible to set a stylesheet.

Comment: As I know you can implement a custom style for `TextEdit` using `QSyntaxHighlighter`. Perhaps this is also an option to do what you want.

Comment: Cheers guys, might delv into modifying the source code to offer QTextMarkdownWriter taking in a Stylesheet but thats a last resort. Will have a look at the QSyntaxHighlighter option, thanks for the suggestion